# Error IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python-2.7

Necesito ayuda para extraer datos de marea (v_tide), quiero que se vayan almacenando los datos de v_tide en una matriz para cada punto de la grilla y para cada paso de tiempo desde la fecha inicial ingresada hasta la fecha final. Intento ir almacenando los resultados de v_tide y el tiempo para luego guardarlos como un .mat y para hacer una gráfica de contornos.

```
import os
import fes
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from numpy import zeros
from scipy.io import savemat 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# CONFIGURACION INICIAL DEL MODELO

os.environ['FES_DATA'] ='/mnt/d/egiraldof/linux/fes2014/northward_velocity'
configuration_file = "northward_velocity.ini"
# configuration_file2 = "/mnt/d/egiraldof/linux/fes2014/eastward_velocity"

# HANDLER

northward_velocity = fes.Handler("ocean", "memory", configuration_file)
# eastward_velocity = fes.Handler("ocean", "memory", configuration_file)
 
# GRILLA PARA INTERPOLAR LAS CORRIENTES DE MAREA

lats = np.arange(1, 2, 0.5)
lons = np.arange(-79, -78, 0.5)

assert lons.shape == lats.shape
size = lats.size

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

# Fecha inicial 
ai, mi, di = 2019, 6, 3
# Fecha final 
af, mf, df = 2019, 6, 4
# Paso del tiempo 
dates = datetime(ai, mi, di)
step = timedelta(minutes=60)

# DATENUM

def datenum(dt):
   mdn = dt + timedelta(days = 366)
   frac = (dt - datetime(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day,0,0,0)).seconds/86400.0
   return mdn.toordinal() + frac

dat=np.empty(lons.shape,dtype='datetime64[us]')

k = 0
while dates < datetime(af, mf, df):
    dat.fill(dates)
    v=zeros((k,1))
    tiempo = zeros((k,1))
    v_tide, _ = northward_velocity.vector(lats.ravel(), lons.ravel(), dat.ravel())
    # u_tide, lp = eastward_velocity.vector(lats.ravel(), lons.ravel(), dates.ravel())
    v[k,1] = v_tide
    tiempo[k,1] = datenum(dates)
    k += 1
    dates += step

# GRAFICAR    

Creating an image to see the result in meters
u_tide = u_tide.reshape((size, size))
u_tide = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(u_tide), u_tide)
plt.figure(1)
plt.title("eastward velocity")
plt.pcolormesh(u_tide)

# GUARDAR RESULTADOS COMO .MAT

savemat('v.mat',{'v':v,'t':tiempo})'
```

No sé hacerlo y me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de ante mano la ayuda.

Comment: Con `v=zeros((k,1))` junto a`k = 0` en la primera iteración del ciclo `while` creas un array vacío (0 filas) y a continuación tratas de indizar sobre el con `v[k,1] = v_tide` lo cual es imposible dado que no tiene un solo item.

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias.